# HtmlAgilityPack multiple element

Tags: c#, regex, html-agility-pack

I have a html document that contains multiple divs

Example:

```
<div class="element">
    <div class="title">
        <a href="127.0.0.1" title="Test>Test</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I'm using this code to extract the title element.

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
var nodes = Web.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@title]");
if (nodes != null)
{
   foreach (var node in nodes)
   {
       foreach (var attribute in node.Attributes)
           if (attribute.Name == "title")
               items.Add(attribute.Value);
   }
}
```

I don't know how to adapt my code to extract the href and the title element 
at the same time.

Each div should be an object with the included a tags as properties.

```
public class CheckBoxListItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Href { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i'm not 100% certain what your question is -but that may just be me. reading again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following xpath query to retrieve only a tags with a title and href :

```
//a[@title and @href]
```

The you can use your code like this:

```
List<CheckBoxListItem> items = new List<CheckBoxListItem>();
var nodes = Web.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@title and @href]");
if (nodes != null)
{
   foreach (var node in nodes)
   {
      items.Add(new CheckBoxListItem()
      {
        Text = node.Attributes["title"].Value,
        Href = node.Attributes["href"].Value
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I very often use ScrapySharp's package together with HtmlAgilityPack for css selection.

(add a using statement for ScrapySharp.Extensions so you can use the CssSelect method).

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using ScrapySharp.Extensions;
```

In your case, I would do:

```
HtmlWeb w = new HtmlWeb();

var htmlDoc = w.Load("myUrl");
var titles = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.CssSelect(".title");
foreach (var title in titles)
{
    string href = string.Empty;
    var anchor = title.CssSelect("a").FirstOrDefault();

    if (anchor != null)
    {
        href = anchor.GetAttributeValue("href");
    }
}
```